# How do I trigger an amp-analytics request when an AJAX request has finished?

Tags: ajax, amp-html

I work at an analytics vendor and we're looking into supporting AMP. I'm looking into beaconing data using amp-analytics. I've got the default `trackPageView` working from the example in the docs. I get a POST request sent to my server when the page is loaded.

However, one of our use cases is sending a beacon after an AJAX request has completed on the page. The idea is that our customer performs an AJAX request to one of our APIs and gets back some data. Some of that data is used to add elements to the DOM and some of that data is sent back to us which acts as a beacon type in our system. One thing I thought of was since that second piece of data is coming from us and then being sent back to us, we could just send it between our services internally and not have the browser need to send it to us at all, but there are a few issues that prevent us from doing this:

- The API in question is high traffic and has caching implemented. There are many more requests being made by browsers than being received by our API's server, and we want to track them all.
- We also want to track data such as browser user agent, so we need that request to be sent by the browser, not our API server.

I have a few challenges here with implementing this in AMP:

- The AJAX request would be performed by an `amp-script` element that our customer would put together. Since `amp-script`s are very sandboxed, would this cause issues having the contents of an `amp-script` interact with the AMP runtime?
- I don't see any triggers in AMP docs that I could use to have the `amp-analytics` request sent when the AJAX request completes.

Usually the questions I put together on StackOverflow are more direct, but I'm mostly confused right now on how to implement this with AMP or whether it's even possible to implement it with AMP at all.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/56028595/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't think I can improve the question. There's no minimal example I can create because I don't know how to create this. I'm asking a question specific to the AMP Project and AJAX to find out whether I can implement something. The AMP Project's support says that StackOverflow is the main forum and that AMP developers frequent it.